# Find the value of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac1{2n}\right)^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit of the sequence as it approches $\infty$   $$\sqrt{1+\left(\frac1{2n}\right)^n}$$

I made a table of the values of the sequence and the values approach 1, so why is the limit $e^{1/4}$?

I know that if the answer is $e^{1/4}$ I must have to take the $\ln$ of the sequence but how and where do I do that with the square root?

I did some work getting the sequence into an indeterminate form and trying to use L'Hospitals but I'm not sure if it's right and then where to go from there. Here is the work I've done

$$\sqrt{1+\left(\frac1{2n}\right)^n} = \frac1{2n} \ln \left(1+\frac1{2n}\right) = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac1{2n} \ln \left(1+\frac1{2n}\right) \\
= \frac 1{1+\frac1{2n}}\cdot-\frac1{2n^2}\div-\frac1{2n^2}$$

Thank you

Comment: You've written two different sequences in your question. The first one you mention is $\sqrt{1 + (1/2n)^n}$, and the second is $(1 + (1/2n))^{n/2}$.

Comment: I think you have messed up with brackets, because the original sequence has the limit of 1 indeed.

Comment: @user68626 I fixed the formatting. In the future, look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: The problem is that your problem is wrong - you want $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n}
$$ The limit, as you wrote it, is $1$, the limit I've written is $e^{1/4}$.

Answer (score 4):

We have $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{x}{n})^n = e^x$. Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{x}{2n})^{2n} = e^x$, then
 taking square roots (noting that the square root is continuous on $[0,\infty)$), we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{(1+\frac{x}{2n})^{2n}} = \lim_n (1+\frac{x}{2n})^{n} = \sqrt{e^x} = e^\frac{x}{2}$, and finally $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{(1+\frac{x}{2n})^{n}} = e^\frac{x}{4}$.

Setting $x=1$ gives
 the desired result.

Comment: Nicely Done +1.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
$$ \left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n=e^{n\log\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)}\sim e^{n\times \frac 1{2n}}=e^{\frac12} $$
So what's the desired limit?

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$
f(n)=\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n
\implies \ln\big[f(n)\big]=-n\ln(2n)
$$
Therefore
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\big[f(n)\big]=\ln\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)\right]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\big\{-n\ln(2n)\big\}=-\infty \\
\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=e^{-\infty}=0
$$
Hence we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n}=\sqrt{1+0}=1
$$